# MultiPolygon - removing polygons intersections in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, geometry, topology

Having a MultiPolygon, I would like to get a MultiPolygon where each polygon has no 'holes' and there are no polygons intersecting with each other.
How to achieve this in PostGIS?

To give you an example, with an input:
`MULTIPOLYGON(((0 20, 20 20, 24 10, 4 10, 0 20)), ((0 20, 8 20, 12 8, -4 10, 0 20)))`
[image]

I would like an output to be: `MULTIPOLYGON(((11 10, 12 8, -4 10, 0 20, 4 10, 11 10)), ((8 20, 20 20, 24 10, 11 10, 8 20)))`
[image]

Another example, for input:
`MULTIPOLYGON(((0 20, 20 20, 24 10, 4 10, 0 20)), ((0 20, 8 20, 12 8, -4 10, 0 20)), ((0 20, 4 20, 4 12, 0 12, 0 20)))`

Expected output would be:
`MULTIPOLYGON(((11 10,24 10,20 20,8 20,11 10)),((3 12,0 12,0 20,-4 10,12 8,11 10,4 10,3 12)),((3 12,4 12,4 20,0 20,3 12)))`

Comment: Your example does not look like the that when I try [it](https://imgur.com/01hfnqf.png), with `st_geomfromtext('MULTIPOLYGON(((0 20, 20 20, 24 10, 4 10, 0 20)), ((0 20, 8 20, 12 8, -4 10, 0 20)))')`

Comment: The first drawn feature is not a valid MULTIPOLYGON. You're in the domain of *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: How'd you get these polygons?  I checked the first and it's definitely invalid.  I was able to 'fix' it by doing this `with polys as
(select row_number() over() id, st_makepolygon(st_makeline(geom)) geom from
(select (st_dumppoints(st_geomfromtext('MULTIPOLYGON(((0 20, 20 20, 24 10, 4 10, 0 20)), ((0 20, 8 20, 12 8, -4 10, 0 20)))'))).*)f group by path[1], path[2])
select st_difference(a.geom,b.geom) from polys a, polys b where a.id != b.id;`

Comment: but that won't work for multipolygons with more that 2 polygons.